# How does Infect interact with Lifelink?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When a creature with Infect and Lifelink puts poison counters on a player, does the controlling player gain life? Do all abilities that trigger on combat damage still occur?

A link to an official ruling would be helpful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, the creature's controller will gain life.

Infect and Lifelink are both abilities that modify how damage is dealt. They're not exclusive in any way; they just mean that the damage dealt has some effects different to what damage normally does. They can happily coexist.

> 119.3b Damage dealt to a player by a source with **infect** causes that player to get that many poison counters.
>   ...
>   119.3f Damage dealt by a source with **lifelink** causes that source's controller to gain that much life, *in addition to the damage's other results.*

The damage is still damage in every way. So it'll still trigger an [Ophidian Eye](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=ophidian+eye), get doubled by [Furnace of Rath](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205268), get prevented by [Samite Healer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=132101) and so on.

The *Scars of Mirrodin* [FAQ document](http://www.wizards.com/dci/downloads/EN_MTGSOM_FAQ_20100922.rtf) says:

> Damage from a source with infect is damage in all respects. **If the source with infect also has lifelink, damage dealt by that source also causes its controller to gain that much life.** Damage from a source with infect can be prevented or redirected. Abilities that trigger on damage being dealt will trigger if a source with infect deals damage, if appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Creatures with Infect still deal damage, so all abilities that trigger* (such as Lifelink) still function.

This is a natural consequence of rule **119.3b** and **119.3d** (and others, like 702.87x, omitted here)

> Damage dealt to a player by a source
>   with infect causes that player to get
>   that many poison counters.

and

> Damage dealt to a creature by a source with wither and/or infect causes that many -1/-1 counters to be put on that creature.

[(Source)](http://www.wizards.com/magic/comprules/MagicCompRules_20101001.txt)

Note that both Infect and Lifelink occur as a consequence of damage being dealt, thus it follows that *any other damage triggered* ability* would also occur.

<sub>*As [AlexC](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/234/alexc) points out, the actually phrase "trigger" can be tricky.  Think "caused to happen, through any of MTG's myriad rules."</sub>

Comment: Best to avoid saying "abilities that trigger on dealt damage", because lifelink is no longer a triggered ability. Lifelink is now simply something that modifies how the damage is dealt.

Comment: Similar to what AlexC said, *Infect* is a static ability, not a triggered one. It changes the properties of how the creature deals damage, rather than replacing damage when damage happens.

Answer (score 5):

Yes to both. The FAQ for *Scars of Mirrodin* states that creatures with infect deal damage to players in the form of poison counters; that's still dealing damage, so lifelink and other abilities that trigger on combat damage take place as normal.